# Linker errors when using intrinsic function via function pointer

Tags: c++, simd, intrinsics

The code below doesn't compile with visual studio 2013. I get linker Error unresolved external symbol(LNK 2019) for the *mm* functions. If i use the functions directly, it all links fine.
Why it doesn't compile? And is there a work-around

```
        #include "emmintrin.h"
        #include <smmintrin.h>
        #include <intrin.h>


        __m128i (*load)(const __m128i*) = NULL;

        if (it::isAligned<16>(ucpSrc, iXOffset * sizeof(unsigned char)) )
            load = &_mm_load_si128;
        else
            load = &_mm_lddqu_si128;
```

Comment: `sizeof(unsigned char)` is 1

Comment: Sure these are plain functions and not functor classes?

Comment: These intrinsics aren't functions, but single machine instructions inserted by the compiler.

Comment: using load in a loop, is there any significant overhead to expect if i wrap the _mm_ - instruction into functions

Comment: @user - I would write two loops, or - better - make sure that everything *is* aligned.

Comment: If you're really asking this question, I suspect that you probably don't understand basic x86 assembly and/or low-level programming. A function call is going to be much worse than a misaligned load on modern processors.

Comment: If you invoke the built-in directly, the compiler just emits the appropriate assembly code into your program at the right place.  There is no function call, so there is no reference to the sympbol.  By indirecting via a function pointer, you make this impossible, so the generated code really has to call a function.   So you need a definition of that function available at link time.  So you need to link against the right library (with /L or whatever).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where some compilers such as gcc and clang use some special annotation on such methods (`static extern __inline __m128d __attribute__((__gnu_inline__, __always_inline__, __artificial__))` for gcc, or `static __inline__ __attribute__((__always_inline__, __nodebug__))` for clang), others (like Intel on Windows and cl, don't and probably do something special under the hood.

Key thing is that these functions are not meant to be considered as functions. They will not show any preamble, implement standard ABI. Those are just a C-syntax way to invoke some assembly instruction, more readable than a `__asm (...)`

I believe you can accomplish this function pointer thing with:

```
__m128i load_aligned (const __m128i* p)
{
    return _mm_load_si128(p);
}

__m128i load_unaligned (const __m128i* p)
{
    return _mm_lddqu_si128(p);
}


__m128i (*load)(const __m128i*) = NULL;

void f(bool a)
{
    if (a)
        load = load_aligned;
    else
        load = load_unaligned;
}

int main()
{
    __m128i a, b ;
    f(argc != 0);
    return 0;
}
```

I would highlight a performance note though: using a function pointer is going to be immensely more expensive than simply using the unaligned load all the time. The overhead of unaligned loads is about a few percents when memory is aligned where calling a function pointer will force you respect the ABI, hence store registers on the stack, most probably go through a few cache misses, etc.